# What's the proper usage of approxEqual()?

Tags: floating-point, d, phobos

At first I thought I could rely on the maximum relative difference only, but I was wrong.  For example, if `a = 0.0`, and `b = 0.5`, their relative difference is `1.0`.  In this case `approxEquals(lhs, rhs, maxRelDiff, maxAbsDiff)` relies on the maximum absolute difference to determine if two floating point numbers are equal.

The two question are:

1. how do I come up with a new maximum relative and absolute difference pair if the default (1e-2, 1e-5) isn't precise enough?  How were `1e-2` and `1e-5` chosen as the default values?  For example, if I choose `1e-4` as my maximum relative difference, what is the maximum absolute difference?
2. How do I adjust the maximum relative and absolute difference values to work properly with `floats` and `doubles`?

Answer (score 1):

checking the [source code](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/math.d#L3904) gives me this (I cut out the implementations for the ranges)

```
bool approxEqual(T, U, V)(T lhs, U rhs, V maxRelDiff, V maxAbsDiff = 1e-5)
{   

    if (rhs == 0)
    {
        return fabs(lhs) <= maxAbsDiff;
    }
    static if (is(typeof(lhs.infinity)) && is(typeof(rhs.infinity)))
    {
        if (lhs == lhs.infinity && rhs == rhs.infinity ||
            lhs == -lhs.infinity && rhs == -rhs.infinity) return true;
    }
    return fabs((lhs - rhs) / rhs) <= maxRelDiff
        || maxAbsDiff != 0 && fabs(lhs - rhs) <= maxAbsDiff;
}
```

this last line is what we'll need to study:

```
return fabs((lhs - rhs) / rhs) <= maxRelDiff
        || maxAbsDiff != 0 && fabs(lhs - rhs) <= maxAbsDiff;
```

in other words the function returns true if the numbers are either *relatively* different by no more than a factor of `maxRelDiff` OR *absolutely* different by no more than `maxAbsDiff`

so using a `maxRelDiff` of `0.01` (or `1E-2`) compares with an accuracy of 2 (decimal) digits

and using `maxAbsDiff` different from 0 allows numbers close to 0 to be considered equal even though there relative difference is greater than `maxRelDiff`

**edit**: basically first decide how accurate the comparison needs to be and choose your `maxRelDiff` based on that, then decide at what point should a number be equal to 0

with the examples in the comments:

```
approxEqual(1+1e-10, 1.0, 1e-10, 1e-30) 
approxEqual(1+1e-10, 1.0, 1e-9, 1e-30)
```

this compares values close to 1 so `maxRelDiff` trumps here and choosing any `maxAbsDiff` (lower than `maxRelDiff`) wont change anything

```
approxEqual(0, 1e-10, 1e-10, 1e-30) 
approxEqual(0, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-30)
```

this compares values close to 0 to 0 so the RelDiff (`fabs((lhs - rhs) / rhs)`) will be 1 and `maxAbsDiff` trumps

Comment: Thanks, but I'm very well aware of the implementation in Phobos.  Yes, the function uses either `maxRelDiff` or `maxAbsDiff`, but you're missing the point.  The questions aren't about how `approxEqual()` works.  Instead, I want to know how to choose a different `maxRelDiff` and `maxAbsDiff` pair than the default one used in Phobos.  I would also like to extend the pair to work properly with `floats` and `doubles`.

Comment: And just to show why the pair need to be carefully chosen: `approxEqual(1+1e-10, 1.0, 1e-10, 1e-30)` and `approxEqual(1+1e-10, 1.0, 1e-9, 1e-30)` are not affect by a poor choice of values for `maxRelDiff` and `maxAbsDiff`, but `approxEqual(0, 1e-10, 1e-10, 1e-30)` and `approxEqual(0, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-30)` are.

Comment: dude last paragraphs read them carefully, and I added a bit of explenation

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't answer your original question, I personally just use `fabs` for floating-point comparisons:

```
return fabs(f1 - f2) < 0.10;
```

Comment: You're calculating the `absolute difference` and comparing it against `0.10`. You can't just rely on absolute difference, and your `0.10` isn't small enough to be practical in most situations.

Comment: If f1 = 0.01 and f2 = 0.03, you have a a fairly large relative difference, but your expression will say "they're the same".

Comment: For the purposes of some code this is the behavior I've wanted.